# How can I avoid creating an extra empty line while using append in a file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, append, txt

I'm creating a file where I am supposed to write, search, delete and print its contents.
When I delete some lines, I have to show again the updated file (without the deleted lines), but whenever I do it, the program creates an extra empty line at the end of the file. How can I fix it?

This is the code I've written (there are some parts in Spanish, because that's my original language):

```
def borrar():
    with open("agenda.txt","r") as f:
        datos=f.readlines()
    print("Digite la cedula del beneficiario a borrar:")
    doc=input()
    for i in datos:
        if i==(doc+'\n'):
            indice=datos.index(i)
            documento=indice
            nombre=indice-1
            telefono=indice+1
            del datos[nombre:telefono+1]
    return(datos)

def actualizar(lis=[]):
    with open("agenda.txt","w") as f:
        for i in lis: 
            f.write(i)
    print("El usuario ha sido eliminado del listado")
```

`li=borrar()`

`actualizar(li)`

I would really appreciate any help I could get!!!

Answer (score 0):

`f.write()` does not actually put a newline at the end of your input text. The issue is in `borrar()` which adds a newline into every item in the list. If you want `actualizar(lis=[])` to remove the newline on the last item of the list you can change it to

```py
def actualizar(lis=[]):
    with open("agenda.txt","w") as f:
        for i in range(len(lis)-1): 
            f.write(lis[i])
        f.write(lis[len(lis)-1].strip())
    print("El usuario ha sido eliminado del listado")
```

All this code does is write the rest of the lines as usual, but remove the newlines from the end of the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the source file, all lines except the last one are `text\n`, and the last one is `text`. If the last line is deleted, the previous `text\n` forms an empty line after itself. You can preliminarily remove `\n` from the last element of the list before outputting the lines to the file:

```
def actualizar(lis):
    lis[-1] = lis[-1].strip('\n')  # add just this line
    with open("agenda.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in lis:
            f.write(i)
    print("El usuario ha sido eliminado del listado")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! It was very useful and I got to fix my little bug :)